# Cakephp 3.6 - Custom Authentication checking on every request

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to insert some authentication rule/check in Cakephp 3. In my case, I want to check if user's IP is still the same when they first authenticated/login.

I am thinking of using AppController's `isAuthorized()` method. And return false on ip change and set the AuthComponent's unAuthorizedRedirect to the logout URL. (I think this is currently the best option)

I found other way but I'm not sure if it is possible. It is
creating a custom Authentication object and add a check ip method that gets called on every request (maybe subscribe it into AuthComponent's startup event. I'm not even sure if this is how event works, I hope I'm correct)

Is using `isAuthorized()` method a good way? Or is there any other "better pratice" for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get there ip addresa through a function which you can get here from stack overflow and
 save that ip with user data in database then at the time of login just check that ip from database if thats same allow him otherwise redirect him you can use ajax also for this

Comment: I know about that, what I don't know is, where to put this "check that ip from database if thats same allow him otherwise redirect him" code.